# Creating data frames via a loop for numbers that not follow each other

Tags: r, loops

I want to import datasets into R as data frames via a loop. The name of the datasets are identical, just the year changes.

```
for(i in 01 04 07 13 15 18){     
datafr[i] <- read_delim("dataset 20[i].csv")   
datafr[i] <- data.frame(datafr[i])    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `lapply` to loop

```
datafr <- lapply(paste0("dataset20", c("01","04","07","13","15", "18"), ".csv"), 
                 read.csv)
```

this will give you list of dataframes in `datafr` which can be individually accessed by doing `datafr[[1]]`, `datafr[[2]]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be

```
lst1 <- lapply(sprintf("dataseet20%02d.csv", c(1, 4, 7, 13, 15, 18)), read.csv)
```